# Spring Boot JPA base configuration taking precendence over app configuration

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Context: Using Spring Boot 0.5.0-M7, MySQL and Commons DBCP, Java config, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` set.

I have defined the application's `DataSource` bean, `JpaVendorAdapter` bean, `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `TransactionManager` beans with specific configuration to support DBCP and some Hibernate settings. On application startup, the `DataSource` is definitely being respected (debug confirms), but the other beans are ignored.  This appears to be as a result of the `JpaBaseConfiguration` class, which is brought into the mix by the `WebMvcConfiguration` and one of it's Security Filters.  In any case, among other things the issue is that the Hibernate setting sets the hbm2ddl (Schema export) to `drop-create`, such that I lose my data every time the server restarts.

I looked through the source and found that there appears to be affordance to set Environment variables that will be respected in the `JpaBaseConfiguration`, however that seems to defeat setting up beans to do the same job.  I have tried excluding some autoconfiguration classes related to Data to no avail.  Is there some other expectation for setting up a non-default data configuration I may be missing?

Comment: The ddl setting should be 'none' for MySQL. Are you sure you weren't using an embedded database?

Comment: Very sure, I see the connection to MySQL in debug logs, my table has data, on restart it's been dropped and re-created (confirmed in MySQL Workbench) Debugging into SchemaExport shows the drop-create setting taking effect.  I will try with a SNAPSHOT build and see if behavior changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dave-syer and @m-deinum for your inputs. Turns out the SNAPSHOT build did the trick, M7 was not respecting my own Beans but now things work as expected.  For posterity I extracted the essence of what I did in my app and applied it to the Boot JPA sample.  The source can be found [here](https://github.com/hoserdude/spring-boot-data-jpa-mysql).  Dave, if you think there's an even simpler way to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the code for Spring Boot 0.5.0.M7 when hibernate is detected (`HibernateEntityManager`) and Springs `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` hibernate will always be configured by default. You can override certain properties by putting them in the application.properties.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy` - Will set the naming-strategy used default = `ImprovedNamingStrategy`.
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` - will set the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto default = create-drop.

General JPA properties you can set

1. `spring.jpa.show-sql` - show sql in the logs
2. `spring.jpa.database-platform` - for hibernate this is the dialect
3. `spring.jpa.database` - The database used (don't use together with database-platform!).
4. `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` - should the ddl be generated, default false (overriden by the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property)

If you want to speficy some none default properties prefix them with `spring.jpa.properties` then they will be added to the `jpaProperties` of the `LocalContainterEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

The inclusion of the `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` isn't related to any other configuration it is simply triggered by the detected of the some classes

```
@ConditionalOnClass({ LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class,
    EnableTransactionManagement.class, EntityManager.class,
    HibernateEntityManager.class })
@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

Comment: I think if you use a snapshot you will find that the individual `@Beans` in the JPA config can be overridden by simply providing your own. Probably with M7 you had to exclude the hibernate autoconfig explicitly.